Migrating spring-mobile-device to Spring 6 javax type mismatch error
I am trying to migrate my app from Spring 5 to 6, with using spring boot 2.7.
According to Spring 6 which does not support javax anymore, I am trying to change javax.* to jakarta.* in my app.
But the problem is, I was using 'LiteDeviceResolver' from spring-mobile-device library to detect client device, and this library is still using javax, occuring type mismatch error.
In this case, what could be the best approach to solve the problem?
Is there anyone else having similiar problem / any library to substitute?

Spring Mobile is no longer active. You need to switch to a different library.
